# Visiting Dubai as an unmarried couple

Tags: legal, dubai

Could we (as a couple) stay together in a hotel in Dubai?

Comment: How they will know you are couples ? maybe you are relatives. maybe you are friends. that will not prevent both of you to sleep in the room. Off the topic but `Kissing in public is strictly illegal and can result in deportation.`[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubai#Sharia_laws)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could be able to stay at a hotel in Dubai as an unmarried couple. Women in Dubai often keep their last names.

Islamic law does prohibit unmarried people from living with each other which does include in a hotel room.

Try to be discreet that you are only a couple (unmarried) in Dubai.
Refrain from calling the other person your girlfriend or boyfriend and also fiance.
So it is not legal, but most of the time they don't act upon it.

Comment: Possible penalty- 1 year in jail and deportation. Quite unlikely to get caught unless you're doing something else sketchy at the same time, but still..

Comment: *...law does prohibit people from living...* do you mean unmarried people from living together ?